# How to stop the latter part of javascript from being called?

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect

I want to redirect user to my mobile site if his screen's width is less than 699.

I am using document.location.href to do that. Redirection is working but problem is sometimes the desktop's css get loaded before the redirection can happen.

[EDIT]

Seems like this is natural thing to happen. Further execution of the html code till it gets redirected actually. But in my case I dont want it to happen. So how do I stop my html from loading images and javascripts etc in case if it has to redirect?

For CSS, I think as said in comments, media would do the job.

I have this following HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
if(screen.width<699)
{
     document.location.href="http://m.example.com";
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/6e0a22.css?v1.3a" />
</head>
<body>
HELLO WORLD
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the stylesheet is cached, the browser will have access to it before the HTTP request to reload the page has completed.

Comment: You can't assume that a Javascript redirect will cease all execution of everything after it on the page – exact behaviour is undefined, as far as I know. One solution would be to add an `else` clause, and only inject the stylesheet into the document inside that..?

Comment: You might use a media query on the style tag to prevent it from loading: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 700px)"`

Comment: I agree with LcSalazar that @media is the way to go. However, if you don't want to do that, another less desirable option is to redirect on document ready/after the page is loaded.

Comment: How about non css things guys. The core intention is not to load anything if the page has to redirect.

Comment: @dragosrsupercool advice to use media queries means that it'd be better to not have to redirect at all.

Comment: @Pointy: But difference between Site Version of the mobile is not just the css. Even the included javascript would be different. So just loading the right css wont help, would it?

Comment: @Shai: How do I implement the else clause. JavaScript's else cant control HTML like PHP, can it?

Comment: just thinking out loud... I haven't tried this yet. See if you can do something like if(screen.width < 699) { window.stop();  document.location.href="http://m.example.com";}

Comment: @NKD: That didnt work :(

Comment: are you using IE? I forgot to mention that it won't work on IE... you may have to do some browser detection like this  .. if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{ 
window.document.execCommand('Stop');
}
else
{
window.stop();
}

Comment: @NKD: I tried that out on chrome!

Comment: =( sorry I tried. i'll let you know if I have more ideas.

Comment: Hey dragosrsupercool, I just tried it out and it it works for me. Maybe i'm missing something. Here is what I did for a quick test: I went here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_tag and then added <script>window.stop();</script> below the <head> tag. Then I click Submit button again, the styling and text no longer rendered. I even added another <h1> before the js to double check.

Comment: @NKDL Yes it did. Seems like window.stop stops the execution after the current script block closes. Later, I was trying to check it by writing alert within the same block. Thanks Mate. Why dont u add this as an answer?

Comment: Why not just dynamically create a white div, absolutely positioned, z-indexed to 10 billion, 100% height/width over the entire site? Even if you cant stop the page itself from loading, you can at least get the appearance it didn't load.

Comment: @Oberst: Because its not just about appearance, but about page load time also how much data packet and battery a user would have to give because of our bad code ;)

Comment: Thats understandable... But the original point of "you are redirecting, if you cant stop the initial page load" then... And, for my own sanity, I just looked up the docs for `window.stop()`. It will still load the page (minus super large things). Which means, you are still sending the html, embedded things, ect. It would end up showing those to the end user. Hence, a white box over everything to stop them from seeing it in the first place. Call `window.stop();`,  create the div, then start your redirect.

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Glad it works. I posted it as answer per your suggestion so whoever it may help don't have to go through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stop the browser from rendering the css by using javascript window.stop().

Tested: 
1. Go to: w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_tag 
2. Add window.stop(); below the  tag 
3. Click on the Submit button again, the styling and text no longer rendered.  
4. Optional: Add another  before the js window.stop() method to double check the behavior. (it should render)

Note: Window.stop() method will not work with IE, use window.document.execCommand('Stop'); instead. 
For more information about this method, please go here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_stop.asp

There are a lot of good suggestions posted here, but this should do the job for the intention of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Because it takes time for the new resource to be fetched, In the meantime, the browser just carries on.

In addition the server might return a `204 No Content` response to the `http://m.example.com` request, in which case, the current page would remain displayed and active.

Comment: How can I make complete execution wait for the response?

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Put a media query in the stylesheet to disable all the styles if the screen width is less than 700 pixels. (It'd probably be better for your site and your users if you did everything with media queries anyway.)

Comment: @Pointy: True! But its not just about stylesheets, I want to stop all possible execution till I have a response.

Comment: @dragosrsupercool - I'm not sure that's possible. You'd have to stop/block the parser. If you do that, you'll also stop the `http://m.example.com` response from ever being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Many options:

1. Use a CSS media query to be selective as to what's shown based on certain criteria
2. Have the server handle the redirection if possible.  You could try to do this via user agents
3. Dynamically create/load the CSS and rest of the page via JavaScript, instead of HTML elements
4. Instead of redirecting, use an empty portal/landing page that directs traffic to the respective site

Comment: 1) OP wants more than just different CSS loaded. 2) Server doesnt detect screen width, UAs can be spoofed. 4) Google frowns upon having redirects on a landing page, and you take a small rank hit because of it (assuming OP cares about SEO).

Comment: Are you just posting edge cases or trying to be argumentative? A lot of this can be spoofed. JS can be turned off. Is that something that should be considered? Sure. Also, it used to matter to SEO, not sure that's the case anymore, but that was more for 301/302 HTTP redirects, Google also changes its ranking engine. If it's an AJAX load (not redirect) then i should matter even less.

Comment: Neither. A lot can be spoofed... But that was a minor part of the comment. JS can be turned off... But why? So much stuff on the web relies on it, it just doesnt make sense. Still matters. And yes, especially for 301 and 302s. My SEO guy is decent about keeping up on this stuff. And yes, if the entire initial load is an AJAX request, then that could be acceptable... Except for GoogleBot doesnt load JS. Thus, your landing page... The page responsible for getting the traffic... Is effectively worthless for ranking. ;) Sure you could use meta tags, but Google parses actual page contents.

Comment: And upon doing a quick search around the internet, it turns out GoogleBot has basic support for JS (as of 2010) which means Im sure it has evolved since then. So... I will retract the statement about a worthless landing page if it uses AJAX. Yes... That could be a feasible option. ;)

Comment: I think there are more recent articles circa 2013 that discuss Google SEO and how JS is less of a factor. The OP is also going to need to be conscious of desktop browsers that have been shrieked and then resized to a wider width.